# how to resolve messagingcenter.subscribe calling multiple times in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

MessagingCenter.Subscribe calling multile times but i called MessagingCenter.send only one time.how to resolve this issue.

I'm subscribe from model's constructor

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, List<string>>(this, "hi", async (arg1, list) =>
        { //code });
```

calling send in android's renderer

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "hi", list);
```

Comment: have you put unsubscribe in your OnDisappearing? and also try to put that subscribe in your OnAppearing rather than the constructor

Comment: One way to avoid multiple copies of `Subscribe`, is to call `Unsubscribe` with same parameters, immediately before you call Subscribe. This deletes any previous subscription.

Comment: Thanks ToolmakerSteve, that worked perfectly.   You both should propose as answers and let people upvote the one they prefer.  Thanks again!